# change values in column of specific tables

Tags: mysql

I need to edit the value of a specific column in certain tables within a database.

*Explanation*:
I need to get all tables within my database that match "table_00" [00 being any number].
in those tables, i need to find any row that has `product_name` as `ice cream`.
if the `product_description` for that row does not contain the word `cold`, i need to add it to the already existing value

how can i do this in the sql command of adminer?
Thank you.

Comment: Show us what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

try update query

```
<?php

function update($table)
  {
    $qry="UPDATE ".$table." SET product_description=concat(product_description, 'freezing cold') WHERE product_name='ice cream' AND product_description NOT LIKE '%cold%' ";
    mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error()."<br>".$qry);
  }
?>
```

and call this function with passing table name as argument

Comment: that will only go for that one table. i don't want to have to rewrite for each table that is of format 'table_00'

Comment: please see my edit above - i need to append the word if its not already there

Comment: @user2306941 hope you got it now

Comment: sorry, but i'm new to sql. i want where to add it where the word `cold` does **not** exist already

Comment: do you want to check cold only or string containing cold

Comment: @user2306941  now see i have modified it according to your requirement

Comment: thanks!! what's the difference between that and `product_description NOT LIKE '%cold%'`

Comment: LIKE returns string containing cold and NOT LIKE return string not containing cold

Comment: you wrote `'cold' IN (product_description)`. i need where 'cold' does NOT exist in the product_description. What is the difference between using "IN" and "LIKE"?

Comment: and IN used to check that whether given string present in string separated with separator  example if you want to check `cold IN ('cold,fun,final')` and if you want to check cold in `ice cream is too cold` then use like

Comment: its according to my knowledge you can get more info on http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp